# Spring Data Jpa как получить объект по id?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, repository

Я новичок в Spring и поэтому не очень понимаю почему без танцев с бубнами я не могу  просто взять и получить из таблицы объект по его id...

Для работы с базой данных я создал

```
public interface TableRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor
```

{
...
}

В основном классе при помощи TableRepository я могу получить список всех элементов из базы данных

```
List<User> userList = (List<User>) tableRepository.findAll();
    for (User us : userList)
    {
        System.out.println(us.toString());
    }
```

Со всеми этими элементами я могу работать как с объектами и делать с ними все что описано в классе-сущности

Когда я пытаюсь вызвать

```
User user = (User) tableRepository.findById(10L);
```

Intellij Idea говорит, что не верная запись и исправляет на

```
Optional<User> user = tableRepository.findById(10L);
```

В результате этого я не могу работать с user как с экземпляром класса-сущности. 
Не понятно на что он ссылается. Нигде толком не описано что такое Optional.

Я могу сам составить запрос, но здесь же есть готовые методы

Как можно просто получить объект по id? Ну или как работать с Optional?
Спасибо за любую помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы наследуете интерфейс от JpaRepository там уже реализованы некоторые методы работы с сущностями в том числе и поиск по id; Благодаря дженерикам `<User,Long>` Spring понимает что какого типа у него идентификатор и объект какого типа он должен вернуть, поэтому в репозитории метод поиска по id писать не нужно.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long>{

}
```

Прописываете в сервисе внедрение объекта репозитория с помощью аннотации `@Autowired`, теперь можно обращаться к методам репозитория

```
@Service
public class UserService{

   @Autowired
   private UserRepository repo;

   public User getUser(Long id){
       return repo.getOne(id);
   }

}
```

Comment: Я тупил сидел. Мне просто надо было пройтись по всем методам. Все тыкал findById.

Comment: @АлексейКлоков можно использовать и `findById(Long)` только он возвращает объект Optional, он предоставляет дополнительные возможности, например так `repo.findById( id ).orElseGet( null );`